# shell script filter du and find by a string inside a file in a subfolder

Tags: linux, shell, cygwin, awk, grep

I have the following command that I run on cygwin:

> find /cygdrive/d/tmp/* -maxdepth 0
>   -mtime -150 -type d | 
>        xargs du --max-depth=0 > foldersizesreport.csv

I intended to do the following with this command:

for each folder under `/d/tmp/` that was modified in last 150 days, check its total size including files within it and report it to file `foldersizesreport.csv`
however that is now not good enough for me, as it turns out inside each

> ```
> /d/tmp/subfolder1/somefile.properties
> /d/tmp/subfolder2/somefile.properties
> /d/tmp/subfolder3/somefile.properties
> /d/tmp/subfolder4/somefile.properties
> ```

so as you see inside each subfolderX there is a file named `somefile.properties` 
inside it there is a property `SOMEPROPKEY=3808612800100` (among other properties)

this is the time in millisecond, i need to change the command so that instead of `-mtime -150` it will include in the whole calculation only 
subfolderX that has a file inside them `somefile.properties` where the `SOMEPROPKEY=3808612800100` is the time in millisecond in future, if the value `SOMEPROPKEY=23948948` is in past then dont at all include the folder
in the `foldersizesreport.csv` because its not relevant to me.

so the result report should be looking like:

> ```
> /d/tmp/,subfolder1,<itssizein KB>
> /d/tmp/,subfolder2,<itssizein KB>
> ```

and if `subfolder3` had a `SOMEPROPKEY=34243234` (time in ms in past) then it would not be in that csv file.

so basically I'm looking for:

> ```
> find /cygdrive/d/tmp/* -maxdepth 0 -mtime -150 -type d | 
>    <only subfolders that have in them property in file 
>    SOMEPROPKEY=28374874827 - time in ms in future and 
>    not in past | xargs du --max-depth=0 > foldersizesreport.csv
> ```

Comment: Please use proper formating in your questions, this ensure readability and probably help getting an answer.

Comment: ok thanks i tried to update it i'm new here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a perl version for the whole thing:

### filter.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec;

# -------------------------- configuration ----------------------------
my %CFG = (
       'propertiesFile' => 'somfile.properties',
       'propertyKey' => 'SOMEPROPKEY',
       'duCommand' => 'du -Bk -s'
);
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

while (my $dir = <>) {
       chomp $dir;
       open(my $F, File::Spec->catfile($dir, $CFG{"propertiesFile"})) || next;
       my ($match) = grep /$CFG{"propertyKey"}=\d+/, <$F>;
       close $F;

       if ($match =~ m/$CFG{"propertyKey"}=(\d+)/) {
               my ($volume, $directories, $file) = File::Spec->splitpath($dir);
               my $command = "$CFG{'duCommand'} $dir";
               # on Windows you might need $volume this assumes Unix-like filesystem
               print $directories . "," . $file . "," .
                       `$command | cut -f1` if $1 > time();
       }
}

exit;
```

### usage

```
find /home/regis/stackoverflow/2937940/* -maxdepth 0 
  -mtime -150 -type d | ./filter.pl
```

### output (with your sample)

```
/home/regis/stackoverflow/2937940/,subfolder1,16K
/home/regis/stackoverflow/2937940/,subfolder2,16K
/home/regis/stackoverflow/2937940/,subfolder4,16K
```

Comment: Thanks!!
I just had to add a test for defined... otherwise I got an error:



if (defined($match) && $match =~ m/$CFG{"propertyKey"}=(\d+)/) {

how do i format this by the way to be code?

Comment: You can use inline code in comment by surrounding text with backticks giving you something like `that` ;)

Comment: Hi
I have a few questions:
what is the meaning of this: `my $dir = <>`
where does it take the $dir parameter from? where does it take the input of the directory? i didn't see any reference to some input...

what is the meaning of `|| next`
i can't figure out how come its processing each directory with like a loop is the `|| next` a loop? if yes a loop of what?
Thanks

Comment: `<>` means stdin; the `|| next` is here to handles `open` failures: when open fails, we skip the directory.